# Audio getting from ByteArray in android

Tags: android, audio-recording, android-mediacodec

I am trying getting audio from NV21 byte array,When I run below code I am getting error this line **inputBuffer.put(input);** name of error**"java.nio.BufferOverflowException"** how can I get audio from byte array?
I guess Ia ma getiing error from ByteBuffer but I cannot solve it, I should increase inputBuffer but how I can't find. Please Help me.

```
       public void init(){
                //initialize Audio Encoder
             File audio_file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/", "audio_encoded.aac");
                try {
                    outputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(audio_file));
                    Log.e("AudioEncoder", "outputStream initialized");
                } catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                try {
                    audioCodec = MediaCodec.createEncoderByType(audioType);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                final int kSampleRates[] = { 8000, 11025, 22050, 44100, 48000 };
                final int kBitRates[] = { 64000, 128000 };
                MediaFormat audioFormat  = MediaFormat.createAudioFormat(audioType,kSampleRates[3],2);
                audioFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_AAC_PROFILE, MediaCodecInfo.CodecProfileLevel.AACObjectLC);
                audioFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_BIT_RATE, kBitRates[1]);
                audioCodec.configure(audioFormat, null, null, MediaCodec.CONFIGURE_FLAG_ENCODE);
                audioCodec.start();
        }
    }

        // called AudioRecord's read
        public synchronized void audioEncoder(byte[] input) {
            Log.e("AudioEncoder", input.length + " is coming");

            try {
                ByteBuffer[] inputBuffers = audioCodec.getInputBuffers();
                ByteBuffer[] outputBuffers = audioCodec.getOutputBuffers();
                int inputBufferIndex = audioCodec.dequeueInputBuffer(-1);
                if (inputBufferIndex >= 0) {
                    ByteBuffer inputBuffer = inputBuffers[inputBufferIndex];
                    inputBuffer.clear();

                    inputBuffer.put(input);


                    audioCodec.queueInputBuffer(inputBufferIndex, 0, input.length, 0, 0);
                }

                MediaCodec.BufferInfo bufferInfo = new MediaCodec.BufferInfo();
                int outputBufferIndex = audioCodec.dequeueOutputBuffer(bufferInfo,0);


    //Without ADTS header
                while (outputBufferIndex >= 0) {
                    ByteBuffer outputBuffer = outputBuffers[outputBufferIndex];
                    byte[] outData = new byte[bufferInfo.size];
                    outputBuffer.get(outData);
                    outputStream.write(outData, 0, outData.length);
                    Log.e("AudioEncoder", outData.length + " bytes written");

                    audioCodec.releaseOutputBuffer(outputBufferIndex, false);
                    outputBufferIndex = audioCodec.dequeueOutputBuffer(bufferInfo, 0);

                }
            } catch (Throwable t) {
                t.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        private CameraProxy.CameraDataCallBack callBack = new CameraProxy.CameraDataCallBack() {

            @Override
            public void onDataBack(byte[] data, long length) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.i(TAG, "length . " + length);

                //audio play
                int min_buffer_size = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(sampleRateInHz, channelConfig, audioFormats);

                audioRecord = new AudioRecord(audioSource,sampleRateInHz,channelConfig,audioFormats,min_buffer_size);

                audioRecord.read(data,0,data.length);
                audioEncoder(data);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try;

> audioFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_MAX_INPUT_SIZE, inputSize);

inputSize should set according to input size. Then inputBuffers capacity will be enough.

Answer (score 0):

Audio encoding offers a little more flexibility than video, in that it's easier to change the size of the input data.

In this case, I recommend checking the size of `inputBuffer` (`inputBuffer.remaining()`) and supplying exactly that amount of audio data. That means if `data` is too big, only put into the `inputBuffer` what will fit, and save the rest for the *next* input buffer. And if `data` is too small, buffer it someplace temporarily, until you get more audio data (enough to fill the entire `inputBuffer`). That's the way this codec is intended to be used.

As an aside: Your code appears to have some problems with confusing video data and audio data, the lifecycle of the `AudioRecord` object, and the proper threading arrangement for capturing video and audio simultaneously. Here are some hints:

- NV21 is a picture format, not audio.
- `onDataBack()` is giving you a picture -- then you're overwriting it with a bit of audio
- In `onDataBack()`, `data` is going to be HUGE -- b/c it contains a picture. And you're trying to read in the whole thing with audio data. Depending on how the `AudioRecord` is configured, it may only read a few bytes. You should check the return value. From the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord.html):

  > Data should be read from the audio hardware in chunks of sizes inferior to the total recording buffer size.
- If you are in need of a better piece of sample code, [this project](https://github.com/OnlyInAmerica/HWEncoderExperiments/blob/master/HWEncoderExperiments/src/main/java/net/openwatch/hwencoderexperiments/ChunkedHWRecorder.java) looks pretty decent.

Comment: thanks for helping my friend.Actually I can't take audio , Where can I take it, if I take it, later What can I do fro the saving simultaneously video and audio.

Comment: Sorry @Diego, this answer was for this specific question. If it is correct, please mark it so. If it leads to a new question, consider making a separate posting.